# Form disappears when resetting Form's TopLevel property

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application I am displaying a new form which needs to be at TopLevel.

So, I am setting

```
someForm.TopLevel = true;
```

Now, I have a checkbox, which will allow user to set it to "not a top level".
When unchecked, i want to set `TopLevel = false`

But when I do this, my form disappears. Does anyone know why?

Here is my code:

```
private void stayOnTop_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.TopLevel = this.stayOnTop.Checked;
}
```

Comment: Just as tip to improve your code: you can directly assign the value of the `CheckBox.Checked` to the `TopLevel` property (or any `bool`, that is): `this.form.TopLevel = this.stayOnTop.Checked`. This way, you save the (unnecessary) `if` block.

Comment: @WeSt Hmm.. Done that

Answer (score 2):

Because your checkbox is named `stayOnTop`, I assume you want to set the [`TopMost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx) property instead of `TopLevel`.

Comment: TopMost isn't doing the thing. While initiating my form i have done this `myForm.Owner = this.ParentForm;`

Answer (score 0):

The setting TopLevel is only meaningful in MDI applications - ones where a parent form has one or more child forms inside it (like Word and Excel used to work).

Answer (score 0):

`TopLevelControl` is the main form of your application. By setting `TopLevel` to `false` the `TopLevelControl` is set to `null`. In that case there is no main form to display for your application. If you add a timer that will switch it back to `true` you will see that it appears again. (It is interesting though that there is no preventing mechanism. For instance it's not possible to add a top level form to another top level form. But you are allowed to get rid of top levels forms entirely.)

So that's why it disappears. If you want it only sent to background you can use `SendToBack()` method. It will change Z-index of the form. So if there is a window behind your control, the control will be moved behind the window.

Comment: @PiotrWolkwski Thanks for the explanation. However `SendToBack()` isn't doing the thing. While initiating my form i have done this `myForm.Owner = this.ParentForm;`

Comment: @SimpleGuy So the form in question isn't a top form? Also, if it's a child form doesn't it work for you when you set the this.TopLevel to false and this.ParentForm.TopLevel to true?

Answer (score 0):

Try these codes :

```
 private void stayOnTop_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(e.checked == true)
  {
    someForm.TopLevel = false; 
  }
  else
  {
    someForm.TopLevel = true;
  }    
}
```